# Adding a touch screen to a non-touch Android device

Tags: android, kernel, touchscreen, odroid

I'm trying to implement a PQ Labs touch panel with an ODROID-X2.  I've managed to get the kernel module compiled and inserted, and a device is created.  dmesg shows that the touch panel is identified, and if I cat the device, I get a steady stream of data.  I know the device is recognized and communicating.

Unfortunately, touch events are not passed through to the UI.  I'm stuck at this point, as my knowledge of the HAL is extremely limited.

How can I get the raw input from my PQ Labs touch panel to pass through to the UI and give me touch events?

Answer (score 1):

Android is equipped with Input Device Configuration files for description of input methods. Here is a comprehensive explanation.

http://source.android.com/tech/input/input-device-configuration-files.html

You may need to add an idc file for your touch screen device.

Comment: I've run across that page many times in my research. I have two problems with it: 1) it's not very descriptive on how to make things work, unless you know what you're doing already, and 2) I have a device that works with the screen (an iStick), but it does not have a corresponding idc.

Comment: I checked on the ODROID, and there is an idc file for the PQ Labs already in place.